# Ошибка Element type is invalid в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Не могу понять с чем связанна ошибка импортирования,ведь я вроде бы импортирую правильно.

routes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {Switch, Redirect, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import {StatPage} from './pages/StatPage'
import {CreatePage} from './pages/CreatePage'
import {FeedbackPage} from './pages/FeedbackPage'
import {AuthPage} from './pages/AuthPage'

export const useRoutes = isAuthenticated => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/stat" exact>
                    <StatPage />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/create" exact>
                    <CreatePage />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/feedback">
                    <FeedbackPage />
                </Route>
                <Redirect to="/create" />
            </Switch>
        )
    }

    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact>
                <AuthPage />
            </Route>
            <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
    )
};
```

./pages/AuthPage (и анолагично другие)

```
import React from "react";

export const AuthPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Auth Page</h1>
        </div>
    )
};
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import {useRoutes} from './routes'
import 'materialize-css'


function App() {
  const routes = useRoutes(true);
  return (
      <Router>
          <div className="container">
              {routes}
          </div>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App`
```

импорт в index.js

```
import App from './App';
```

[github](https://gitlab.com/OlegGalansky/uproject)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

если Вы используете **SSR** (**server side rendering**), то вместо метода `render` используйте метод `hydrate`. например так:

`ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`

если дело не в этом, то попробуйте импортировать `App` таким образом:

```
export default function App() {
  const routes = useRoutes(true);
  return (
      <Router>
          <div className="container">
              {routes}
          </div>
      </Router>
  );
}
```